# how to use python3.8 with ROS Kinetic in a node (import rospy)?

Tags: ros, python3, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am using ROS kinetic which supports python2.7.
I want to run a node with python3.8 using rosrun.

when I used a shebang to test the script without any "import rospy" it worked.

but when I include "import rospy" to turn the script into a node and be able to send values, it gives me the following error:
in 
import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

I would greatly appreciate any idea to make ROS kinetic itself use python3.8 instead of python2.7 and fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398699/how-to-use-python3.8-with-ros-kinetic-in-a-node-(import-rospy)?/) by [AA A](https://answers.ros.org/users/54264/aa-a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on 2022-04-07**:
Here are some similar answers that might help you:

[ROS Kinetic and Python3 general](https://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/)

[rospy and python3 specific](https://answers.ros.org/question/347402/import-error-for-rospy-in-python36-script/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you update your system to a later version of ROS that uses Python 3.8? Noetic should do it.

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2022-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1